# Stacked area chart using ggplot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to create a stacked area chart for the following data (.txt file):

```
Year    Frequency_FQR1  Frequency_FQR2  Frequency_Others    Frequency_PnimB
1989    0   0   0   0
1990    0   0   0   0
1991    0   0   0   0
1992    0   0   0   0
1993    0   0   0   0
1994    0   0   0.166666667 0.166666667
1995    0   0   0   0
1996    0   0   0   0
1997    0   0   0.083333333 0.083333333
1998    0   0   0   0
1999    0   0   0   0
2000    0   0   0   0
2001    0.041666667 0.041666667 0.166666667 0.25
2002    0   0.045454545 0.045454545 0.090909091
2003    0   0.086956522 0.130434783 0.217391304
2004    0   0.108695652 0.304347826 0.413043478
2005    0.101694915 0.084745763 0.169491525 0.355932203
2006    0.00754717  0.433962264 0.064150943 0.505660377
2007    0.017679558 0.409944751 0.097237569 0.524861878
2008    0.011350738 0.282633371 0.077185017 0.371169126
2009    0.005780347 0.225433526 0.046242775 0.277456647
2010    0.020966272 0.1349134   0.053783045 0.209662716
```

And the data continues a bit further.

I am using ggplot and tried with:

```
data <- read.delim ("test.txt")

ggplot(data, aes(x=Year)) +
geom_area(aes(y=Frequency_FQR1, x=Year)) +
geom_area(aes(y=Frequency_FQR2, x=Year)) +
geom_area(aes(y=Frequency_Others, x=Year)) +
geom_area(aes(y=Frequency_PnimB, x=Year)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1989, 2022))+
theme_classic()
```

I am not getting the expected plot and also I am not sure what to give input for y.

I want the graph to be stacked with Frequency_FQR1, Frequency_Others, Frequency_FQR2, and a curve for Frequency_PnimB.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, you should pivot to long format first.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
 pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(y = value, x = Year, fill = name)) + 
 geom_area()
```

[image]

Also, I see you note you'd like a curve for PnimB, you could split it out into a separate aesthetic like this:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
    mutate(line = ifelse(name == "Frequency_PnimB", value, 0))


df2 %>% filter(name != "Frequency_PnimB") %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = value, x = Year, fill = name)) + 
    geom_area() + 
    geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = Year, y = line))
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 1989:2010, Frequency_FQR1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.041666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.101694915, 
0.00754717, 0.017679558, 0.011350738, 0.005780347, 0.020966272
), Frequency_FQR2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.041666667, 
0.045454545, 0.086956522, 0.108695652, 0.084745763, 0.433962264, 
0.409944751, 0.282633371, 0.225433526, 0.1349134), Frequency_Others = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.083333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 
0.045454545, 0.130434783, 0.304347826, 0.169491525, 0.064150943, 
0.097237569, 0.077185017, 0.046242775, 0.053783045), Frequency_PnimB = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.083333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.090909091, 
0.217391304, 0.413043478, 0.355932203, 0.505660377, 0.524861878, 
0.371169126, 0.277456647, 0.209662716)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = c("data.frame"))
```